# Func with derived parameters

Tags: c#, inheritance, delegates, func

I have several methods whose parameter is a derived type:

```
bool Method1(ChildType1);
bool Method2(ChildType2);
```

With `ChildType1` and `ChildType2` heritating from ParentType.

I want a delegate that can accept either Method1 or Method2 but get compilation errors:

```
Func<ParentType, bool> MyDelegate =  Method1;
```

> Error 1   No overload for 'Method1' matches delegate 'Func < ParentType,
>   bool>'

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Use delegate covarianc/contravariance. See here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173174.aspx

Comment: @Marteen delegates are covariant in their *return* types (and contravariant in their parameters). The OP needs covariant parameters, which is not possible.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What's the underlying need?

Comment: This was just to prevent using tons of switch case in my code. I would have called the appropriate method rather than having to switch the context every thime I need to invoke one of the methods.
Was an attempt of optimization.

Comment: There are better ways to do this. You can use a `Dictionary<Type, Delegate>` to hold the methods and then cast the delegate as `Func<T, bool>` based on the `T` type of the parameter. That would eliminate the `switch` code.

Comment: @AD - If you ask another question that is more accurately about what you're trying to do I can provide you with some sample code that I think you'll like.

Comment: I get the idea but I am not sure how to declare the dictionary and how to invoke the method in my example.
Declaring the following:
 Dictionary<Type, Func<ParentType, bool>  > dictionary_name ;
would lead o the same error I suppose?

Comment: @ Enigmativity
Well if you can suggest a way to declare a variable where I can allocate either Method1 or Method2 in my example, I ll manage to adapt the solution to my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76993/discussion-between-a-d-and-enigmativity).

Comment: @AD - Do check out this code - https://dotnetfiddle.net/A1aGbE

Comment: @Enigmativity : Nice code, I do thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Think about what would happen if that was possible:

```
Func<ParentType, bool> MyDelegate =  Method1;

//Method1 does not accept a parameter of type ChildType2, but MyDelegate does
MyDelegate(new ChildType2());
```

This doesn't work for the same reason why you can't cast an instance of `List<Dog>` to `List<Animal>` - because then you'd be able to call `animals.Add(cat)`, which would have to throw an exception at runtime because cats can't be added to a list of dogs.